# How to use the HTTP Authentication Manager of jMeter

Tags: testing, jmeter

I am new to jMeter, I want to know how to use the HTTP Authentication Manager using jmeter. I pass user name and password in the HTTP request as well as in the Authentication Manager, but I can't get the response of the index page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Authentication depends on how your web app is expecting credentials.

If it's parameters through the HTTP request, the authentication manager won't work for you.

If it's server authentication, then follow the link below. (Server authentication is when your web browser gives you a pop-up box to login, instead of a webpage form)

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager

Answer (score -2):

In case credentials are being passed as parameters, a solution that worked for me is setting JMetter in proxy mode so samples are automatically generated based on browser interactions with the web application. You might need to make some modifications to the resulting samples (in particular you'll want to add a HTTP Cookie Manager), but you'll have a test plan that reproduces the desired interactions. Helpful links:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Proxy_Server
- http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/80479-how-to-use-jmeter-for-login-authentication

Comment: Can downvoters explain what they find missing in my answer? That would help me improve my answers in the future. Thanks in advance.